2024 Community Moderator Election Results
Engineering's Moderator election #3 has come to a close. Since there were not enough candidates for a competitive election, we simply appointed the candidates who nominated themselves:

They will be joining the existing crew shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!
